# Unable to load correct page in Bottle Python

Tags: python, bottle

i'm having a hard time understanding why i can't load the "/ticket" page properly, but i can load the "/" fine. I should have the /ticket page running and able to type the information under username and email but i'm missing something.

I'm running Python 3.10.4

["localhost:8080/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJe6L.png)

["localhost:8080/ticket"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maBVg.png)

```
import os
import bottle
import base64
import traceback

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from binascii import hexlify
from html import escape
from bottle import route, request, get, post, response


page = '''
<html>
<head><title>Welcome</title></head>
<body>
<p><h2>Welcome, %s!</h2></p>
<p><h3>There are %s tickets left</h3></p>
<p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
'''

key = os.urandom(32)
iv = os.urandom(16)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())


def get_ticket(username, email, amount):
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder() 
    message = padder.update("%s&%s&%d" % (username, email, amount)) + padder.finalize()
    ct = encryptor.update(message) + encryptor.finalize()
    return base64.b64encode(ct)

@bottle.route('/', method=('GET', 'POST'))
def default():
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(128).unpadder()
    try:
        ticket = bottle.request.get_cookie('ticket')
        if ticket:
            message = decryptor.update(base64.b64decode(ticket)) + decryptor.finalize()
            username, email, amount = (unpadder.update(message) + unpadder.finalize()).split('&')
            return page % (escape(username), escape(amount),
                'Already done' if amount == '1' else 
                'Go ahead')
        else:
            return '<html><body><p><a href=/ticket>Fill in the forms</a></p></body><html>\n'
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise bottle.HTTPError(status=401, body=e.message)

@bottle.post('/ticket', ['GET', 'POST'])
def ticket():
    username = bottle.request.forms.get('username')
    email = bottle.request.forms.get('email')
    if username and email:
        ticket = get_ticket(username, email, 1)
        bottle.response.set_cookie('ticket', ticket)
        return '<html><body><p>Thank you!</p></body></html>\n'
    raise bottle.HTTPError(status=400, body='Please fill in the form')

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: didn't you mean `@bottle.route` not `@bottle.post`?

Comment: Bottle.post is supposed to be used when there a request.form.get isn't it ?

Comment: Bottle.post means the endpoint will only accept post requests.

Comment: @2e0byo I changed

@ bottle.post('/ticket', ['GET', 'POST'])

To

@ bottle.route('/ticket')

But still get the error 400 page. I should be able to see the ticket page and input the username, and mail, but it's not happening ^^

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code hits an error is that you never actually serve a form for the user to fill in (and thus your code correctly errors). I don't really understand your flow at all, but I think it's supposed to look something like this:

- user navigates to `/`
- if user doesn't have a ticket, user is sent to a login page
- user logs in and gets a ticket
- user goes *back* to `/` and requests it, this time with a ticket (authentication cookie) in the get request.

Mind you I don't understand what these tickets are, as they appear to be a hashed form of whatever the user submits and the constant `1`, but I guess there's more logic coming along later.

Currently there are quite a few problems with the setup:

- `/` accepts post requests, but never does anything with them.  It also doesn't make sense for it to accept post requests, since `POST` is to *send* data to a server.
- your `/ticket` endpoint would do what you want if you sent it a form, but you never serve a form for the user to fill in.
- your `/ticket` endpoint needs to return one thing if you make a `GET` request to it, another completely different thing if you make a `POST` request.  This is *possible*, but it's a bad way to build these endpoints in general.
- after getting the cookie the browser is simply going to throw it away.  If you want to do cookie-based authentication, you need to store the cookie and handle it (normally you use this with JS in the webbrowser, and take care to add it to all requests).

If we add a login endpoint:

```py
@bottle.route("/login")
def login():
    return """<html><body>
    <form action="./ticket" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body></html>"""
```

And edit the previous `href` to point us to `/login`, we now get a form. Filling that form in and pressing 'submit' correctly sends the data to the `/ticket` endpoint, calling the code to get the ticket. Unfortunately that fails for unrelated reasons (your hashing needs bytes, not strings) but that's a different question.

I suggest you have a think about the overall flow of this application---what are these tickets for, and where is the user supposed to end up?  Regardless you will need to serve some kind of login form at some point.  You probably want this to be a static file, by the way, and served as such---see the bottle docs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are correct the flow i was envisaging is what you described.

Regarding the encryption, i try to apply some of the info i got from
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/

But i'm not exactly familiar with the encryption process, which is why i'm trying to work on it.
When you say the hashing needs to be bytes. That's why the base64 is encoding the strings.

Comment: @folichon try your token function: the error occurs *before* you try to base64 encode anything.  However even if corrected the token doesn't work as it's not returned in the request correctly.  Rather than trying to implement your own encryption---particularly as this authentication doesn't actually authenticate anything!---you are probably *much* better off using a ready-rolled library.  But note that if you're going to use this token for anything you need to modify your frontend to send it when it makes requests---which means using JS to make the requests.  But that's a different question.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try and check for a different way of doing this. I appreciate the help!

Comment: but wait i don't understand why the bottle.request.forms.get is not even serving the form under the "/ticket" location when i go there directly.

Like in the example given here:
https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/examples/2529/bottle-retrieve-form-data

I'm just trying to create a little webapp that would provid an hypothetical ticket when the username and email is registered in the form, and encrypt the data.

Comment: The form is not being served *because there is no form to serve*.  Where do you think bottle is going to get an http form from to serve it? What should it look like?  How should it be encoded?  The linked example (not from the bottle docs btw) is only able to *recieve* form data: it's apparently an example of how to use the 'request' object.  In my example I served a form (on a different route) which then submits to the form endpoint.

Comment: Damn it! you're right! I thought the bottle.request.forms.get would prompt the forms, i misundertood what i read!

So, if i wanted to serve the input that a person entered in both forms (from your code example, which worked btw), back into "def get_ticket", adding an amout of 1, in order to create the ticket, what should be different ?

Comment: If you want to _pass_ the input, have a look at the `form` element--particularly the `action` paramter.  If you want to implement your flow as I described it---you can't, unless you use JS to do the authentication, keep the token in memory in the browser, and then pass it when you do the request.   If you're just trying to authenticate you might like to look at http basic auth, which is fine over ssl.  In any case this is really off-topic for this question.